# Laravel Eloquent Subquery inside a join with alias

Tags: sql, laravel

I like to select all the information from the first table and count the data from a specific column from the second table with their relationship with each other.

This is the SQL Query

```
Select * from emp_informations e inner
join(Select SUM(latein) as totallate, enrollnum from dtrs where latein > 0 
and (date_in between 2015-03-01 and 2015-03-31) and (date_out between 2015-
03-01 and 2015-03-31)  group by enrollnum)dtrs on dtrs.enrollnum=e.EmpID 
group by EmpID
```

What is the laravel code for this query??

```
$employees=DB::select(DB::raw('Select * from emp_informations e join (Select 
SUM(latein) as totallate, enrollnum from dtrs where latein > 0 and date_in 
between 2015-03-01 and 2015-03-31 and date_out between 2015-03-01 and 2015-
03-31  group by enrollnum)dtrs on dtrs.enrollnum=e.EmpID group by EmpID '));
```

but nothing shows..

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my problem this is the code..

```
$employees = DB::table('emp_informations')
    ->join(DB::raw("(Select SUM(latein) as totallate, enrollnum from dtrs 
    where latein > 0 and (date_in between '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-31' and 
    date_out between '2015-03-01' and '2015-03-31') group by 
    enrollnum)dtrs"), function($join)
    {
        $join->on('emp_informations.EmpID', '=', 'dtrs.enrollnum');
    })
    ->groupBy('EmpID')
    ->get();
```